# BIRT: Fetch values from a data set to another data set

Tags: dataset, birt, computation

I am trying to get a value from a parent data set to a child data set. The CPX row (**BLUE** box) is the parent data set and the rows TP, BT and LI (**YELLOW** box) are under child data set.

The box in **GREEN** needs to display the difference of two values in **RED** boxes under child parent.

**Computation:**
443.34mm - (0.88 * 2) = ***441.58mm***

I am trying to display the difference of two values but they are in different data sets and I cannot populate their columns in parent data set since they are from child data set. Anyone here knows how to do it in simplest way? Thank you!

[image: Sample data]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Pass the parent columns as data set parameters to the child data set. Use the parameter binding dialog od the client layout container to support the current values.